# How do you get all three badges in Donkey Kong Country Returns levels?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-returns

At the end of each donkey kong level you get a star badge for getting all the **K.O.N.G.** letters and a puzzle badge for getting all the puzzle pieces.

What is the third badge for?

Answer (score 8):

You get it by **earning a bronze, silver, gold, or shiny gold medal in time attack mode**.  You'll get a better medal the faster you finish a level.  All you really need to fill in the circle is to get a bronze medal, which is an achievement to be celebrated.  Earning a time attack medal *doesn't* count toward the percent complete number which is shown on the file select screen.  If you want to get 100%, you only have to get all the KONG letters and puzzle pieces.

Thank heaven, as those **time attack medals are sadistically, fiendishly, mercilessly, wickedly hard to get**.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can retry the level to run a Time-trial.

Beating the time on the Time-trial version of the level gives the third badge.