# How do you get the third badge in Donkey Kong Country Returns?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-returns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get all three badges in Donkey Kong Country Returns levels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15518/how-do-you-get-all-three-badges-in-donkey-kong-country-returns-levels)

On each level there are three circles, one for the KONG that is the red one, the second for the puzzle pieces that is the green one, and what is the third one? You can see this more clearly when you hit level summary.

Answer (score 1):

It is for the time-attack medals. After you beat a level, you can replay it in time-attack mode. Finish the level fast enough, and you earn a bronze, silver, gold, or shiny gold medal. This medal appears as the third icon.